# Can I use GPIOs to bit-bang in SENT protocol

Tags: gpio, bit-bang, stm8

I want to use a `STM8` controller for a project(as I am familiar with micro).This controller gets the data from sensor and process it and sends data to another controller through the `SENT/SPC` protocol. But issue here is, `STM8` doesnot support `SENT` protocol. I thought to adopt `bit bang` method and use the `GPIO` pins to transmit the data, but I am in little confusion whether my decision is right or wrong. Can anyone suggest/help me in this issue? By using `bit-bang` method may I face any other issues?

Comment: The "another controller" what ever that is, only supports SENT/SPC, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah the other one supports SENT/SPC